# The number of elements in a conjugacy Classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, lie-groups

I have this group
$$G= \left\{ A = (a_1 ,a_2,a_3) \in GL_3(\mathbb{C}) :a_i \in \left\{\pm  \pmatrix{1 \\ 0\\ 0} , \pm  \pmatrix{0 \\ 1\\ 0} , \pm  \pmatrix{0 \\ 0\\ 1} \right\} \right\}.$$
I know that This group is an product of cyclic group (-+1) with S3, so while I'm checking the conjugacy classes to this group, I got stuck of found the number of the elements in the classes that map to elements of order 2 ,their conjugate must be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&*&0\\*&0&0\\0&0&*\\
\end{array}\right)$

the determinant is + or - 1, I know the order of the elements is 2 or 4, and there’s  4
classes from this kind of map, but I get stuck of found the number of the elements of the 4 classes how can I found it, I thought that I must have for least 8 elements but its wrong
I’ll be thankful for help.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says the size of the conjugacy class of $g$ is $\vert G: C_G(g) \vert$?  Use that on the Sylow subgroups of $G$.

Comment: That's the third time that this question has been asked in two days!